# Jquery iPad Hover / Click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a div on ipad that upon one click will expand, then on the next click actually open up to fill the browser window, I am not sure of how to do this, this is my code:

```
var elems = $( ".event" );

    elems.bind("click touchstart", function(){

    if ( $(this).hasClass( "hovered" ) ) {

        $(this).removeClass("hovered");
        $(this).addClass("open");
        elems.not(this).addClass('closed');
        $(this).find('.close-btn').fadeIn();

    } else {

        $(this).removeClass("hovered not-hovered");
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
        elems.not(this).addClass('not-hovered');

    };

});
```

So Basically on the first click the div (.event) will expand a little, taking on the class "hovered", if the class exists on the div and you click it should expand to fill the screen (taking on the class "open")... it seems to work in my broswer but not on ipad, any ideas?

Heres my dev link just incase: nyeto.com - check it on your ipad

Comment: "hover" + iPad = aaarrrrgh. Even though you're not using an actual hover event, the word is meaningless in this context.

Comment: lol a fake hover then, 1 click expands a litte, 2 clicks opens it full... any possibility of that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Yeah thats what I am thinking, does anyone know where I can find docs on "touchend" and such? I am having a hard time find it

Comment: The iOS docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html), but they're not trivial reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS fires a `click` event shortly after `touchstart+touchend`, so your code may be firing twice in quick succession.

Try cancelling both events:

```
elems.bind("click touchstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
```

---

Another approach is to fire the `click` event on `touchstart` and cancel the latter:

```
elems.bind("touchstart", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
elems.bind("click", function(e) {
    // rest of your code
```